# Desenvolver (unwrap) envolturas (wrapper)

Tags: c++, template

#### Introducción.

En C++ no podemos crear contenedores de referencias:

```
std::vector<int&> vri;
```

> ```
> In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int&>’:
> required from ‘class std::allocator<int&>’
> required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<int&, std::allocator<int&> >’
> required from ‘class std::vector<int&>’
> required from here
> error: forming pointer to reference type ‘int&’
>        typedef _Tp*       pointer;
>                           ^~~~~~~
> ```

La implementación interna de los contenedores, requiere el uso de punteros al tipo contenido, lo que generaría el tipo prohibido *puntero a referencia*.

Por suerte, existe la plantilla [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
int x{1}, y{2}, z{3};
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vr{x, y, z};
for (auto &v : vr)
    ++v;
std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra `2 3 4`.

#### Problema.

Estoy desarrollando una librería de filtros para contenedores de C++, por ejemplo el filtro `where` recibe un contenedor y devuelve `std::reference_wrapper` a los objetos del contenedor que cumplan el criterio:

```
template <typename container_t> auto range(const container_t &container)
{ return std::tuple{std::begin(container), std::end(container)}; };

template <typename container_t, typename predicate_t>
auto where(const container_t &container, predicate_t predicate)
{
    auto [b, e] = range(container);
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*b)>;
    using reference = std::reference_wrapper<type>;

    std::vector<reference> result{};

    std::copy_if(b, e, std::back_inserter(result), predicate);

    return result;
}
```

Así, el siguiente código muestra `2 3 6 7`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (auto &x : where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }))
        std::cout << x << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

El problema surge al concatenar filtros:

```
for (const auto &x :
    where(where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }), [](auto n){ return n & 0b1; })) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

> ```
> no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const std::reference_wrapper<const std::reference_wrapper<const int> >’)
>    std::cout << x << ' ';
>    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
> ```

Dado que el primer `where` devuelve un `std::vector<std::refernce_wrapper<int>>`, el segundo trabajará sobre `std::vector<std::refernce_wrapper<const std::refernce_wrapper<const int>>>`.

#### Intento.

Para solucionar el problema, he creado una plantilla que si recibe un `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, desenvuelve el tipo `T` interno:

```
template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<type_t>>
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
using unwrap_t = typename unwrap<type_t>::type;
```

El desenvolvedor se desenvuelve<sup>1</sup> bien:

```
int main()
{
    using ri = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
    using rf = std::reference_wrapper<float>;
    using rri = std::reference_wrapper<ri>;
    using rrri = std::reference_wrapper<rri>;

    std::cout
        << typeid(int).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<int>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(float).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<float>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(ri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<ri>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rf).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rf>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rri>).name() << '\n'
        << typeid(rrri).name() << '\t' << typeid(unwrap_t<rrri>).name();

    return 0;
}
```

Y muestra los datos esperados<sup>2</sup>:

> ```
>   i   i
>   f   f
>   St17reference_wrapperIiE    i
>   St17reference_wrapperIfE    f
>   St17reference_wrapperIS_IiEE    St17reference_wrapperIiE
>   St17reference_wrapperIS_IS_IiEEE    St17reference_wrapperIS_IiEE
> ```

Entero y flotante (`int`, `float`) quedan inalterados, envoltura de entero queda desenvuelta, y las envolturas anidadas se desenvuelven un nivel.

Pero no funciona dentro de `where`:

```
template <typename container_t, typename predicate_t>
auto where(const container_t &container, predicate_t predicate)
{
    auto [b, e] = range(container);
    using type = unwrap_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*b)>>;
    //           ^^^^^^^^ <--- Desenvuelve el tipo del iterador.
    using reference = std::reference_wrapper<type>;

    std::vector<reference> result{};

    std::copy_if(b, e, std::back_inserter(result), predicate);

    // Chivatos sobre la función
    std::cout
        << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"
        << '\t' << "decltype(*b) = " << typeid(decltype(*b)).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "unwrap *b = " << typeid(unwrap_t<decltype(*b)>).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "type = " << typeid(type).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "reference = " << typeid(reference).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "unwrap type = " << typeid(unwrap_t<type>).name() << '\n';

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (const auto &x :
        where(where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }), [](auto n){ return n & 0b1; })) {
        std::cout << &x << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Los chivatos dentro de `where` indican que el desenvolvedor funcionó en la primera llamada, mas no en la segunda:

> ```
>   auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]
>       decltype(*b) = i
>       unwrap *b = i
>       type = i
>       reference = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       unwrap type = i
>   auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const int> > >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:2)>]
>       decltype(*b) = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       unwrap *b = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       type = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
>       reference = St17reference_wrapperIKS_IKiEE
>       unwrap type = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
> ```

En la primera llamada, el contendedor de entrada es `std::vector<int>`, la des-referencia del iterador (`decltype(*b)`), la desenvoltura (`unwrap_t<decltype(*b)>`), el tipo (`type`) y la desenvoltura del tipo (`unwrap_t<type>`) son `int`, sólo es `std::reference_wrapper` el tipo `reference`.

En la llamada anidada, el contendedor de entrada es `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>>` y todos los tipos (salvo `reference`) son `std::reference_wrapper<const int>`, como si la desenvoltura no se estuviese aplicando.

#### Pregunta.

¿Qué está fallando en la plantilla para desenvolver envolturas? Sospecho que tiene algo que ver con la propagación de `const`.

Código disponible en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRdb9MwFH1ufsVVkdqEeagb302WFwQSLwOh8oC2yXIdN7NInci56aiq/nWK42SJ6crGEC@Rc@499@tcmxfFccr5bvdEKp5ViYBI5iVqwZax12MrwTHXLoJVkQkXWFSKo8wVy1yUZWmuJV7/Fg3XhaComcQy9jwUyyJj2OKKLQXwXCGTSmiKMbAKc9BMpcIHcE0w6n6MIYANaIGVVlBiMp3aAjf2OBepVH7nHJDGQ6jEAbchbMPHFGPwEv9Qz/8p5lA1zexiz2hUcYRK3WhWeBtvUJVSpdYMZ61X6D0mSGTr0GIhtFBc0BorhG7ViuN/TdJwmhxmSA3PerR5W0czJXMIH1oI0vMLLRLJjWedxipzc22Kv1cZ4rL6c1B3Z0NczAmIK1Nmp3KrSXjbfqUSobO1OdJ2Eu3klvlKUJucYpQIntVm/@k8iMO90d1OI3KZ/egx2ssR9xE6rz7vIcUMwRtYe3N3o84tNiHKKsPNtnPhebGmcuHXrbf7OGf8O5WqFBqF9htG4AwvcMgVeoNBFAGln7@8n82@0Q9fz9/NPn46pxQMPLxUw8ZhfIlji7jDMX0Ma7D@l4nvmoJntc5@AJarxntR7grhBtqzPhDrQIC/YLliuNQO3@fXU2sfhmam5vp4nlQIS7Nlvl1DRzVYbSYETgicEnhO4AWBlwReEXhN4A2Bt1bBhXFrV94u8OgHTNuL0HxXBC6ufGtTQfcuKRjBZH4yMS9NcJ9DbQ9M253WdSsmx92GJqaX3e4nX2QsLXfHhnDGj45O2S8)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>[*Pun intended*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pun%20intended).

<sup>2</sup>Esos son los [nombres que el compilador da a los tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Has tratado de especializar aún más la plantilla unwrap para que al pasar un contenedor de reference_wrapper te devuelva el tipo del tipo?  Me parece que vas a enfrentar el mismo problema al concatenar más de un nivel, donde tendrías un vector de rw a rw a rw...a T.

Comment: Estaba pensando que el comentario que tienes de la propagación de const--si es el problema--podría resolverse con referencias universales, que preservan si un objeto es o no const (me imagino si estás haciendo uso de vínculos/enlaces estructurados, auto return type, etc., estás familiarizado con perfect forwarding). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Usé el compilador de visual studio para ver que otra información sobre el tipado informaba. El resultado que mostró en consola fue:

```
        decltype(*b) = int
        underlying_type = int
        type = int
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        decltype(*b) = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        underlying_type = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        type = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<class std::reference_wrapper<int const > const >
```

Evidentemente hay algún problema con la resolución del unwrap_t tanto en visual studio como en gcc. La cuestión es que si reemplazamos

```cpp
decltype(*b)
```

por

```cpp
typename container_t::value_type
```

el resultado en consola es:

```
        decltype(*b) = int
        underlying_type = int
        type = int
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        decltype(*b) = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        underlying_type = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        type = int
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
```

Pero como el const se propaga el compilador da el siguiente error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<int> > > >’ and ‘const int’)
```

Esto se soluciona si hacemos const al tipo contenido por el vector que estamos creando.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename container_t> auto range(   container_t &container   ) { return std::tuple{std::begin(container), std::end(container)}; };
template <typename container_t> auto range(const container_t &container) { return std::tuple{std::begin(container), std::end(container)}; };

template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
struct unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<type_t>>
{
    using type = type_t;
};

template <typename type_t>
using unwrap_t = typename unwrap<type_t>::type;

template <typename container_t, typename predicate_t>
auto where(const container_t &container, predicate_t predicate)
{
    auto [b, e] = range(container);
    using underlying_type = std::remove_const_t<typename container_t::value_type>;
    using type = unwrap_t<std::remove_reference_t<underlying_type>>;
    using reference = std::reference_wrapper<const type>;

    std::vector<reference> result{};

    std::copy_if(b, e, std::back_inserter(result), predicate);

    std::cout
        << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"
        << '\t' << "decltype(*b) = " << typeid(decltype(*b)).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "underlying_type = " << typeid(underlying_type).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "type = " << typeid(type).name() << '\n'
        << '\t' << "reference = " << typeid(reference).name() << '\n';

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for (const auto &x : where(where(v, [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }), [](auto n){ return n & 0b10; }))
        std::cout << x << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado en gcc:

```
auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]
    decltype(*b) = i
    underlying_type = i
    type = i
    reference = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
auto where(const container_t&, predicate_t) [with container_t = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const int> > >; predicate_t = main()::<lambda(auto:2)>]
    decltype(*b) = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
    underlying_type = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
    type = i
    reference = St17reference_wrapperIKiE
2
3
6
7
```

Resultado en visual studio:

```
        decltype(*b) = int
        underlying_type = int
        type = int
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        decltype(*b) = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        underlying_type = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
        type = int
        reference = class std::reference_wrapper<int const >
2
3
6
7
```

Comment: Gracias por aportar algo nuevo a esta olvidada pregunta. El problema es que el tipo contenido no tiene por qué ser `const` ¿Y si luego queremos operar sobre los datos filtrados?

Comment: Para eso se debe quitar el const del parámetro container_t. Pero si haces eso no vas a poder anidar la función where.